# Dynamic attributes with Rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, dynamic-attributes

I'm learning MongoDB through the Mongoid Ruby gem with Rails (Rails 3 beta 3), and I'm trying to come up with a way to create dynamic attributes on a model based on fields from another model, which I thought a schema-less database would be a good choice for.

So for example, I'd have the models:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String
  field :token, :type => String
  field :info_needed, :type => Array

  embeds_many :members
end

class Member
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :account, :inverse_of => :members

end
```

I'm looking to take the "info_needed" attribute of the Account model and created dynamic attributes on the Member model based on what's inside.  If club.info_needed was ["first_name", "last_name"], I'm trying to create a form that would save first_name and last_name attributes to the Member model.

However, upon practice, I just keep getting "undefined method first_name=" errors on the Member model when trying to do this.  I know MongoDB can handle dynamic attributes per record, but how can I get Mongoid to do this without an undefined method error?

Comment: I'd ask that you select my answer below as the answer as it's more accurate than the currently selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid doesn't really support it.

I happen to have [asked](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/bbab975df6a40c7/632792f360f68d3d?lnk=gst&q=dynamic#632792f360f68d3d) this at Mongoid group myself.

It is possible when you create new document, like this:

`account = Account.new(:some_dynamic_field => "...")`

Answer (score 31):

Mongoid now supports Dynamic Fields.  Their documentation can be found here:
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields

Basically it warns that you have to be slightly careful how you set dynamic fields as it will raise a no method error if you attempt to use the getter and setter methods for a field that did not exist in the document.

[],[]= are shortcuts for read_attribute(),write_attribute() , and should be used if you do not set `dynamic_attributes = true` in your `./config/mongoid.yml file` , otherwise you'll get a no method error.

Setting `allow_dynamic_fields: true` can be risky, as you might pollute your data/schema with unintended fields caused by bugs in your code. It's probably safer to set this to `false` and explicitly use [],[]=

```
# Raise a NoMethodError if value isn't set.
person.gender
person.gender = "Male"

# Retrieve a dynamic field safely.
person[:gender]
person.read_attribute(:gender)

# Write a dynamic field safely.
person[:gender] = "Male"
person.write_attribute(:gender, "Male")
```

Comment: It's been removed in 4.0

Answer (score 9):

Be sure to set `allow_dynamic_fields: true` in `mongoid.yml`. Example:

```
defaults: &defaults
  allow_dynamic_fields: true
  parameterize_keys: true
  persist_in_safe_mode: true
  raise_not_found_error: true
  reconnect_time: 3
  use_object_ids: false

development:
  <<: *defaults

...
```

Comment: Yea, I had done that, but was still having trouble.  If you've done this though, and it's been working for you, perhaps mongoid was updated since I posted this question.

Comment: downside to setting `allow_dynamic_attributes: true` is that it is per database, and that you might pollute your schema with unintended fields, caused through bugs in your code.  Probably safer to set this to `false` and to consciously use [],[]=

Answer (score 2):

interesting article about Dynamic Attributes with Mongoid and Rails 3.1: http://paul-wong-jr.blogspot.com/2012/03/dynamic-attributes-and-mongodbmongoid.html

To access only the dynamic key/value pairs or dynamic attribute names, see also:
 [List dynamic attributes in a Mongoid Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319867/list-dynamic-attributes-in-a-mongoid-model/11604721#11604721)