# List dynamic attributes in a Mongoid Model

Tags: ruby, mongodb, dynamic, mongoid

I have gone over the documentation, and I can't find a specific way to go about this. I have already added some dynamic attributes to a model, and I would like to be able to iterate over all of them.

So, for a concrete example:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :status, type: String, default: "pending"
end
```

And then I do the following:

```
Order.new(status: "processed", internal_id: "1111")
```

And later I want to come back and be able to get a list/array of all the dynamic attributes (in this case, "internal_id" is it).

I'm still digging, but I'd love to hear if anyone else has solved this already.

Comment: Looks like you are asking the same question as [Dynamic attributes with Rails and Mongoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699239/dynamic-attributes-with-rails-and-mongoid)

Comment: Close. My question is about how to use them, rather than if they can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just include something like this in your model:

```
module DynamicAttributeSupport

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def dynamic_attributes
      attributes.keys - _protected_attributes[:default].to_a - fields.keys
    end

    def static_attributes
      fields.keys - dynamic_attributes
    end
  end

end
```

and here is a spec to go with it:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "dynamic attributes" do

  class DynamicAttributeModel
    include Mongoid::Document
    include DynamicAttributeSupport
    field :defined_field, type: String
  end

  it "provides dynamic_attribute helper" do
    d = DynamicAttributeModel.new(age: 45, defined_field: 'George')
    d.dynamic_attributes.should == ['age']
  end

  it "has static attributes" do
    d = DynamicAttributeModel.new(foo: 'bar')
    d.static_attributes.should include('defined_field')
    d.static_attributes.should_not include('foo')
  end

  it "allows creation with dynamic attributes" do
    d = DynamicAttributeModel.create(age: 99, blood_type: 'A')
    d = DynamicAttributeModel.find(d.id)
    d.age.should == 99
    d.blood_type.should == 'A'
    d.dynamic_attributes.should == ['age', 'blood_type']
  end
end
```

Comment: i get an undefined method _protected_attributes, but with it removed everything works well

Answer (score 5):

this will give you only the dynamic field names for a given record x:

```
dynamic_attribute_names = x.attributes.keys - x.fields.keys
```

if you use additional Mongoid features, you need to subtract the fields associated with those features:
e.g. for `Mongoid::Versioning` :

```
dynamic_attribute_names = (x.attributes.keys - x.fields.keys) - ['versions']
```

**To get the key/value pairs for only the dynamic attributes:**

**make sure to clone the result of attributes(), otherwise you modify x !!**

```
attr_hash = x.attributes.clone  #### make sure to clone this, otherwise you modify x !!
dyn_attr_hash = attr_hash.delete_if{|k,v| ! dynamic_attribute_names.include?(k)}
```

or in one line:

```
x.attributes.clone.delete_if{|k,v| ! dynamic_attribute_names.include?(k)}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what I ended up doing is this. I'm not sure if it's the best way to go about it, but it seems to give me the results I'm looking for.

```
class Order
  def dynamic_attributes
    self.attributes.delete_if { |attribute| 
      self.fields.keys.member? attribute 
    }
  end
end
```

Attributes appears to be a list of the actual attributes on the object, while fields appears to be a hash of the fields that were predefined. Couldn't exactly find that in the documentation, but I'm going with it for now unless someone else knows of a better way!

Comment: your code modifies 'self' - you should clone the attributes hash first

Comment: I should have entirely caught that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

try .methods or .instance_variables

Comment: This was helpful to me, easier than trying to sort through the docs looking for a list of supported methods on each class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I liked the clone approach, so I wrote one too. From this you could easily build a hash of the content too. This merely outputs it all the dynamic fields (flat structure)

```
 (d.attributes.keys - d.fields.keys).each {|a| puts "#{a} = #{d[a]}"};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get any of the above solutions to work (as I didn't want to have to add slabs and slabs of code to each model, and, for some reason, the `attributes` method does not exist on a model instance, for me. :/), so I decided to write my own helper to do this for me. Please note that this method includes **both dynamic and predefined fields**.
**helpers/mongoid_attribute_helper.rb**:

```
module MongoidAttributeHelper
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(AttributeMethods)
  end

  module AttributeMethods
    def get_all_attributes
      map = %Q{
          function() {
            for(var key in this)
            {
              emit(key, null);
            }
          }
        }

      reduce = %Q{
          function(key, value) {
            return null;
          }
        }

      hashedResults = self.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true) # Returns an array of Hashes (i.e. {"_id"=>"EmailAddress", "value"=>nil} )

      # Build an array of just the "_id"s.
      results = Array.new
      hashedResults.each do |value|
        results << value["_id"]
      end

      return results
    end
  end
end
```

**models/user.rb**:

```
class User
   include Mongoid::Document
   include MongoidAttributeHelper
   ...
end
```

Once I've added the aforementioned include (`include MongoidAttributeHelper`) to each model which I would like to use this method with, I can get a list of all fields using `User.get_all_attributes`.

Granted, this may not be the most efficient or elegant of methods, but it definitely works. :)