# undefine methods in mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I want to be able to dynamically undefine mongoid fields. I tried the undef method in the context of the class object. Unfortunately it does not work, as shown below:

```
class MongoTest
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :abc, type: Integer
  field :def, type: String
end

m = MongoTest.new
m.fields.keys
 => ["_id", "abc", "def"]

MongoTest.class_eval { undef :abc, :abc= }
m.fields.keys
=> ["_id", "abc", "def"]
```

But undef does actually undefine the method from being invocable:

```
m.abc
NoMethodError: undefined method `abc' for #<MongoTest _id: 554013e86d61632f57000000, abc: nil, def: nil>
```

I'm a little confused as to why this method still shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `undef` will remove the methods that Mongoid's `field` adds but it won't do anything to the fields themselves. Why are you trying to undo `field` calls?

Comment: @muistooshort I am building a dynamic CRM, where you can add and remove fields to objects through a UI. When someone selects to delete field, I just don't want that field in the system anymore.

Comment: Are you sure Mongoid is the right tool for this job? Removing the field requires editing the `MongoTest` class not just the database.

Comment: @muistooshort don't you think mongodb is a better choice than mysql or postgresql for dynamic fields?

Comment: I don't think it is a question of MongoDB versus SQL, PostgreSQL or MySQL might even be better since you can ask a table what its schema is but each document in a MongoDB collection can potentially be different. The main issue is whether or not a standard ORM/ODM such as Mongoid or ActiveRecord is the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining `static` fields on the model and attempting to remove them at runtime, you should use `dynamic`fields in the first place.

In order to use `dynamic` fields you must [add the following line to your model](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields):

```
include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
```

And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699239/dynamic-attributes-with-rails-and-mongoid) you will need to set `allow_dynamic_fields: true` in `mongoid.yml`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, the only thing is when I want to get all the field keys e.g. m.fields.keys, dynamic fields are not present.